# Corrupted ntfs volume mounting problem

Tags: linux, hard-disk, corruption

I have a 2TB Seagate EHDD. I was working fine before. But for sometime it is not mounting in windows and linux. Windows hags up while i plug the HDD. I tried it with linux, and it shows some mounting problem as follows.

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/pErSoNaL dAtA:
>   Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1"
>   "/media/user/pErSoNaL dAtA"' exited with non-zero exit status
>   13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024
>   usa_ofs: 72  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument Record 10 has no FILE
>   magic (0x0) Failed to open inode FILE_UpCase: Input/output error
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error NTFS is either
>   inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
>   SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
>   then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
>   important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it
>   and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
>   /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
>   for more details.

As given in the error info, I tried plugging it in windows and running chkdsk /f. But HDD does not respond in windows. Then i tried nxtfsfix in linux. The result is as follows.

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

> Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000 
>   size: 1024   usa_ofs: 72  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument Record 10
>   has no FILE magic (0x0) Failed to open inode FILE_UpCase: Input/output
>   error FAILED Attempting to correct errors...  Processing $MFT and
>   $MFTMirr... Reading $MFT... OK Reading $MFTMirr... OK Comparing
>   $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed
>   successfully. ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size:
>   1024   usa_ofs: 72  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument Record 10 has
>   no FILE magic (0x0) Failed to open inode FILE_UpCase: Input/output
>   error

Below is the fdisk details.

> Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary. Partition
>   table entries are not in disk order.
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920
>   bytes Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x9be30dda
>
> Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type /dev/sdb1
>   2048 3907031039 3907028992  1.8T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a way to solve it. I used the free backup utility called testdisk.
It is available for both windows and linux. I used it to backup my data from the HDD. Then i used the partition manager to delete the complete partition. And at last created the new partition. Now it works fine.